# Tkinter scrollbar doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm working on some basic graphics for a chat client for a uni project. Most things seem to work fine, however i cannot get the scrollbar to work, despite extensive searches on the problem.

```
chat = Tk()
chat.title('')

###
canvas = Canvas(chat, width = 450, height = 750)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas, command = canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.pack()
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
topframe = Frame(canvas, bg = 'dark slate blue', width = 450, height = 750)
topframe.pack(side = TOP)
topframe.propagate(0)
botframe = Frame(chat, bg = 'dark slate blue', width = 450, height = 50)
botframe.pack(side = BOTTOM)
###

my_msg = StringVar()
my_msg.set('Message...')
entrybox = Entry(botframe, textvariable=my_msg, bg='slate blue', width=47,
                     font = 'SansSerif 12')
entrybox.pack(side=LEFT)
sendbutton = Button(botframe, text = 'Send', width = 4, height = 1,
                        bg = 'gray11', fg = 'white', command = sendmsg)
sendbutton.pack(side=RIGHT)
entrybox.bind('<Return>',enter_pressed)
entrybox.bind('<Button-1>',clearentry)

chat.mainloop()
```

Basically I have a frame, inside a canvas; all messages are displayed as Message widgets inside the frame, but once the messages reach the end of the screen, I obviously want to be able to scroll down. My scrollbar appears greyed out and I cannot interact with it. I've found people mentioning an extra canvas.configure statement but I haven't been able to make that work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Canvas contains no contents to scroll!  Child widgets such as your `topframe` are simply layered on top of the Canvas, you have to use `.create_window()` to make them actual items of the Canvas instead.  You will also need to set the Canvas's `scrollregion` to let it know the bounds of the area to be scrolled.

Comment: scrolling items on Canvas can be complex for beginner. Search examples with [ScrolledFrame and ScrolledCanvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas). Or maybe use `Listbox` or `Text`.